# capture screenshot/frame of a video file

Tags: python, video, screenshot, frame

is there a way to capture a single frame of a video file in python?
it could also be done by command line. im using handbrakecli to convert the videos,
but i would need some screenshots of it too.

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first check out [PyFFmpeg](https://github.com/mhaller/pyffmpeg).

> PyFFmpeg is a wrapper around FFmpeg's
>   libavcodec, libavformat and libavutil
>   libraries whose main purpose is to
>   provide access to individual frames of
>   video files of various formats
>   (including MPEG and DIVX encoded
>   videos). It also provides access to
>   audio data.

It is also possible using `ffmpeg`, so call that using `subprocess`. A simple search will give you the command required to extract a frame from a video file. Just call that command using `subprocess` and that should do it.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex                          # to split the command that follows
>>> command = 'ffmpeg -i sample.avi'      # your command goes here
>>> subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

The similar procedure applies to `handbrakecli` or whatever you might use. Just call the appropriate command.

Comment: i see i can get it with ffmpeg like: ffmpeg -i <input-file> -ss <time> -vframes 1 file%d.jpg but i could not find anything similar for handbrake

Comment: That you have to find, I have just given how you will call that using Python. Try searching, the solution should be fairly trivial.

Comment: command = 'ffmpeg -i inputVideo.webm -ss 100 -vframes 1 output.jpg' worked for me